# google signup is not working on first click on element but after that working fine. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-signin

Hello I am using google api to sign in to my web application . Its working fine . But the problem is the sigin is automatic in my application, but for signup i want start that process after user check the term&condition and the process will start.

below is the JS code:

```
var googleUser = {};
var auth2;
var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'XXXXXX',
                
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".googlesignin", function(e){
            
            if($('#terms').is(":checked")){
                termsvalue='1';
                $("#termsValidation").hide();
                $("#termsValidation").attr("data-hint", $("").text()); 
                attachSignup(document.getElementById("googlesignin"));
            }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                termsvalue='';
                $("#termsValidation").show();
                $("#termsValidation").attr("data-hint", "Please agree by clicking checkbox");
                return false;
            }
        });
        
    });
};



function attachSignup(element) {  

    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) { 
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
            var googleurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
             $.getJSON(googleurl, function(result){
                $("#rfirstname").val(result.given_name);
                $("#remail").val(result.email);
                $("#googlePicture").val(result.picture);
                $("#google_id").val(result.sub);
                    
            });
            
        }, function(error) {
        parsed_error = JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2);
        parsed_error = JSON.parse(parsed_error); 
          if(popup_closed_by_user!='popup_closed_by_user'){
            alert(popup_closed_by_user);
          }   
        });
  };

  startApp();
```

this is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="XXXXXX">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="terms">
    <div id="googlesignin" class="googlesignin"><img alt="" src="google.png" style="vertical-align: initial;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In first click it's not working but after that it's working fine. need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hej @Jeevan, you need to give us html also to be able to build and replicate your issues - see details here > https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: also you are attaching `click` event @body child `$("body").on("click", ".googlesignin"..` inside `gapi.load` ? that is what tricks you..

Comment: @KresimirPendic this is my html
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" id="terms">
 <div id="googlesignin" class="googlesignin"><img alt="" src="google.png" style="vertical-align: initial;"></div>
</div>

Comment: @KresimirPendic if i am writing the click event outside gapi load then nothing is happen. Do you have any better solution?

Comment: @KresimirPendic one more thing if i call my attachSignup() function outside my click event then it's working fine but that time i am not able to check the checkbox condition.

Comment: can you please try my modify code below (just comment startapp and add below code) see if that resolves it

Comment: You have two click handlers on the same element. The first one is set after `gapi.load` finishes, by `$("body").on("click", ...);`. Then when it's clicked, the handler sets the second click handler at `auth2.attachClickHandler`. Then, when the element is clicked the second time, the second handler runs. So that's why much of the code doesn't run until the second click. Probably you could just call `attachSignup` directly instead of setting it as a handler, and then move all the logic from that function (checking whether `$('#terms').is(":checked")` etc) into the `function(googleUser)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to try to comment last line of `startApp` and add below hooks for when jQuery is loaded.. like this, hope this will help

```
  // startApp();
  
  (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      startApp();
    }); // - end DOCREADY
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: yes, i already tried this but no impact. it's working on second click again.